# Why am I a Boltzmann brain?

Tags: thermodynamics, big-bang, anthropic-principle

The Boltzmann brain hypothesis states that a big-bang-causing entropy fluctuation is larger than a brain-causing entropy fluctuation, therefore, you are much more likely to be a BB rather than a wet brain. But this doesn't make sense to me (maybe I don't understand?) because when $10^{80}$ particles fluctuate into one location, they will ALWAYS create a big bang whereas when $10^{22}$ particles fluctuate into one location, they will create a BB only one out of every ($10^{22}$)! times. The chance of $10^{80}$ particles fluctuating into one location seems absurdly more likely than the chance of $10^{22}$ particles fluctuating into a specific pattern.

The way I see it, there are four events, and their respective rarities, to compare here:

- the event where $10^{22}$ particles fluctuate into one location (event rarity a)
- the event where $10^{22}$ particles fluctuate into my BB (event rarity b),
- the event where $10^{80}$ particles fluctuate into one location (event rarity c)
- the event where $10^{80}$ particles evolve into my WB (event rarity d).

I don't understand why BBH says $(a \times b) > (c \times d)$

What am I not understanding here?

Comment: IMHO the Boltzmann Brain hypothesis is wild speculation.  Nobody knows what would, physically, constitute a Boltzmann brain. Nobody knows what makes a big bang happen.   Nobody knows how to calculate the probability that a human-class brain will emerge via evolution on an Earth-like planet.  We *do* know that evolution is vastly more efficient at producing organized structures than random association of atoms is.

Comment: "We do know that evolution is vastly more efficient at producing organized structures than random association of atoms is."

That's why I only stated an inequality.

Comment: Yup,  I'm agreeing with you.

Comment: I don't think you are. My view is that it is virtually impossible to be a Boltzmann brain. We can actually use this inequality to infer an upper bound on the probability of a big bang occurring which can infer the size of the universe; the less likely the BB, the more room there is for a large universe. This also implies no aliens; if observers are likely, why didn't we occur in a small universe?

Comment: I agree (for what that matters!) that a Boltzmann brain is essentially impossible.  However, we don't have a clue how a Boltzmann brain would be structured, so estimates of its probability of existence are pretty much meaningless.  And, consequently, any calculations based on a value for the probability of a Boltzmann brain would be pretty much meaningless.  By the way, I don't quite understand *d*.  Surely you don't mean a wet brain containing 10^80 particles.  That would be rather large.

Comment: Event rarity d is is where a big bang universe creates galaxies, stars, planets, and hopefully life evolves and hopefully intelligent life evolves and hopefully my exact brain fluctuates into existence from that baseline.

Comment: For your * exact* brain, the probability of emergence is on the order of 1/googolplex.  For a brain of comparable capacity, the probability is more on the order of 1.  But why ask for your exact brain?

Comment: Should we move this conversation to chat?